# My code throws recursive error. Can somebody explain to me what's wrong with my base code in recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I'm finding out the minimum payment to make, to ensure the debt is fully settled after 12 months

The unpaid credit balance is compounded every month by (a/12)%

I just started learning recursion and couldn't figure out why my base code for recursion is wrong. The console throws up recursion error. Here's part of the code.

> #minPayment (3329,0.2)

```
def minPayment (cb, a):

'''
cb = initial credit balance
a = annual interest (in decimals)
'''

  x = 0
  unpaid = cb-x
  inc = (cb-x)*(a/12)

  def mintha (x):
     totalPay = unpaid + inc

     if (12*x - totalPay) >= 0:
         return x

     else:
         totalPay = unpaid + inc
         return mintha (x+10) 


 return mintha (x)
```

Expected result = 310
Actual result = 290

Comment: `def mintha (x): return mintha (x)` it looks like endless loop.

Comment: use `print()` to display values in variable and messages which part of code is executed - it helps to see what code is doing. Or learn how to use debuger :)

Comment: At a quick glance, it looks like the bottommost `return mintha(x)` won't ever be reached, since each clause in the if/else above it will return something. Also: `return totalPay and mintha(x+10)` seems like it will return a boolean, while `return x` should return a number, which seems a little wonky.

Comment: @DustinMichels in python `(x and y)` is the same as `y if x else x`, no booleans involved

Comment: @MichaelVeksler Yes, I'm just realizing that. Interesting. So if `totalPay` is truthy, it will return `mintha(x+10)` and if not it will return `totalPay`?

Comment: @Aqib It is totally unclear what you are trying to do. Can you give some numeric examples? The function does not resemble the way that compounded interest works

Comment: @DustinMichels yes, exactly. A truthful integer `totalPay` is when `totalPay != 0`

Comment: If you have a comment to explain what a variable is, then the variable name is bad, and you have an unnecessary comment. Change the variable name to match the comment.

Comment: What is increment? Monthly debt increment, in the world of banking and compounded interest, is usually a percentage of the remaining debt, so it can't be a constant

Comment: the code you write in post, can't be executed because of undefined vars: a, cb

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I've put down the correct code. I really appreciate all of your feedback. I'll take the time to thin about your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems with the code:

- The function `mintha` is called again in the return statement of the function, `return mintha(x)` which can cause an endless loop
- In the `return` statement for the `else` clause: `return totalPay and mintha (x+10)` you are calling the function again. This can lead to recursion problems if the maximum depth is reached.

So, we correct the code and assign some hypothetical values for `x`, `cb` and `a` and give this a go. While returning the values, we round them to the nearest integer.

```
x = 0
cb = 25000
a = 50000
unpaid = cb-x   # unpaid balance
inc = unpaid*(a/12)  # increment 

def mintha (x):

    '''
    x is the minimum payable per month to pay off debt (round to tenth) 
    '''

    totalPay = unpaid + inc      # total credit balance, including the 
                                #    interests

    if (12*x - totalPay) >= 0:
        return round(x)

    else:
        totalPay = unpaid + inc
        return round(totalPay)

print(mintha(3000))
#Output:
104191667
```

P.S.: I'm not entirely sure about the math behind this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see what's happening without knowing what values all the variables could have, but I can say this:

1. It looks like the bottommost `return mintha(x)` won't ever be reached, since each clause in the if/else above it will return something.
2. The else clause, which ends `return totalPay and mintha (x+10)` has slightly unintuitive behavior. As @MichaelVeksler pointed out above, this will return `mintha(x+10)` if `totalPay` is false (ie, 0) and otherwise it will return `totalPay`.

So, function return if/else logic you have written is something like this:

```py
if (12*x - totalPay) >= 0:
    return x
else:
    if totalPay == 0:
        return totalPay
    else:
        return mintha (x+10) # recurse
```

I would closely examine the condition `if (12*x - totalPay) >= 0:` and make sure it will eventually evaluate to true, as that would break you out of the infinite recursion. (It seems like it may never become true since `totalPay` is increased [maybe?] with every `totalPay = unpaid + inc` statement.)

The other way to break out of the infinite recursion is if `totalPay` is 0, but again I'm not sure this is what was intended.

> *Note:* This answer does not speak to issues with the code producing a meaningful answer, it just tries to explain why infinite recursion is happening.